# Setting virtual hosts on mac (Mac OS X Lion 10.70.4) using AMPPS

Tags: macos, localhost, vhosts

It's my first time trying to set a virtual host and I am a little bit lost. I want to set the virtual name "tp3.localhost".

Questions:

1. My AMMPS url is **localhost:8585**. In the hosts file do I have to write **127.0.0.1 tp3.localhost** or **127.0.0.1:8585 localhost**?
2. The code I wrote in the httpd-vhosts.conf is the following:

NameVirtualHost tp3.localhost

```
<VirtualHost  tp3.localhost>
    <Directory "/Applications/AMPPS/www">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
    ServerName tp3.localhost
    ServerAlias localhost:8585 127.0.0.1:8585
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Applications/AMPPS/www/cgi-bin/"
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/AMPPS/www"
    ErrorLog "/Applications/AMPPS/apache/logs/error.err"
    CustomLog "/Applications/AMPPS/apache/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

AMMPS is an alternativ for MAMP.

Answer (score 1):

I think your VirtualHost statement should include the port.

When calling the ULR you need to call it as tp3.localost (see ServerName) so it gets triggered.

So tp3.localhost is a name which should exist somewhere in your DNS or /etc/hosts file so it can be resolved to 127.0.0.1 (or ::1 for IPv6)